# В дизайнере не отображаются элементы

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

**Это исправленная и дополненная версия вопроса.**

Создаю проект стандартным образом (я только начал осваивать написание программ под андроид).
[image: первый шаг]
(выбор API на возникновение ошибки не влияет никоим образом, проверено опытным путем)
[image: второй шаг]
[image: третий шаг]
[image: четвертый шаг]
И на выходе получаю проект, но дизайнер не отображает `TextView`, да и любые другие элементы. Видно сообщение об ошибке
[image: конечный результат с ошибкой]

работаю в Ubuntu 16.04. Версия студии
[image: о программе]

Если проект скомпилировать и запустить в эмуляторе или на устройстве, то текст отображается.

Пока месть удалось найти решение [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio)
В `/res/values/styles.xml` нужно изменить

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">...</style>
```

на

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">...</style>
```

Такое решение меня напрягает малость. Какой-то костыль получается. А когда я закончю с дизайном интерфейса, мне надо назад возращать настройку стиля?

В build.grandle(Module.app) зависимости такие

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: а что он ругается, что пишет на кнопке?

Comment: Попробуй Апи поменять над тулбаром 28 у тебя, сделай, 27 или 26.

Comment: @KostyaM  Я переписал вопрос.

Comment: @McDaggen Я переписал вопрос.

Comment: Каких версий библиотеки `AppCompat` и `Design`?

Comment: @McDaggen а где и как можно это посмотреть (узнать)?

Comment: Отправьте, пожалуйста, свой build gradle  module app, возможно там не подключена нужная либа,хотя это странно

Comment: implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' Эти строки есть?

Comment: @KostyaM добавил в вопрос какие у меня зависимости

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, возникла некая проблема с более новой версией библиотеки `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3"`. Из-за этого не загружался `ActionBar` и preview ломался. Следует использовать более стабильную `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` версию.
Рад, что смог Вам помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос очень общий, в вашем случае необходимо обновить ConstraintLayout, после удалить абсолютные величины (а лучше для начала удалить Button и всё содержимое) и сделать рендер. Но я дам ответ немного подругому, чтоб помочь всем, кто встречает такую проблему.

В данной ситуации у `Design` или `Preview` вкладки есть кнопка в верхнем углу, которая открывает панель Ошибок и Предупреждений (Show Warning and Error) выглядит она примерно так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

там вы можете посмотреть все ошибки связаные с рендером вашего окна и исправить таковые, также там есть кнопка `refresh` которая позволит обновить исправленные ошибки, если успешко то ваш preview должен перерисоваться. Выглядит примерно так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, я для пущей ясности переписал вопрос.